# Algorithm runs in 5s but page only load after 1.5m

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, algorithm

I have the following code:

`itens#show`

```
start_t = Time.now

@itens = @item.get_tf_idf_recommendations

finish_t = Time.now
puts "time: " + (finish_t - start_t).to_s + "sec"
```

*(model)item#get_tf_idf_recommendations*

```
def get_tf_idf_recommendations

  data = Array.new
  itens = Array.new

    Item.all.includes(:genders).each do |item|
        aux = Array.new 
        item.genders.each do |gender| 
            aux << gender.id
        end
        data << aux
    end

    tf_idf = TfIdf.new(data).tf_idf

    similaridade = Hash.new

    Item.where("id != ?", self.id).each do |item|
        similaridade[item.id] = similaridade_com(tf_idf, item)
    end

    similaridade = similaridade.sort_by { |id, score| score }.reverse.take(5)

    similaridade.each { |id, score| itens << Item.find(id) if score > 0 }

    return itens

end
```

*(model)item#similaridade_com* (similarity_with)

```
def similaridade_com(tf_idf,item)

  my_terms = tf_idf[self.id - 1]
  itens_terms = tf_idf[item.id - 1]

  soma = 0.0

  my_terms.each do |k, v|
    soma += v.to_f * itens_terms[k].to_f
  end

  sim = soma / itens_terms.size

  sim.nan? ? 0 : sim

end
```

After run the method I got the following output: `Time: 5.03214sec`

```
...
Rendered itens/_avaliacoes.html.erb (3.7ms)
Rendered itens/_content_recommendation.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered itens/show.html.erb within layouts/application (693.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (5.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6396ms (Views: 1194.7ms | ActiveRecord: 61.7ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

But the page only renders after **1.5m** as you can see in the trace of Google Chrome:

```
Blocking    0.987 ms
DNS Lookup  624.962 ms
Connecting  0.412 ms
Sending 0.129 ms
Waiting 1.5 min // :(
Receiving 1.441 ms
```

The worst is that i can`t realize why the code is running in 5sec and the page only render after 1.5m. The only tip I know is that if I comment out this part of the code, it runs immediately

```
    Item.all.includes(:generos).each do |item|
        aux = Array.new 
        item.generos.each do |genero| 
          aux << genero.id
        end
        data << aux
    end
```

Comment: How big is your Item table, how many records? I also see a lot of N+1 query problems in your code. Can you also show your itens/show.html.erb? The rendering takes ages, maybe you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: I think I finally got it! 
I have this table structure |itens| 1 --- n |generalizations|n ---- 1|genders|.
`Item.all.size = 1752`
`Generalization.all.size = 4050`
`Gender.all.size = 43`

My biggest mistake was in this line `Item.all.includes(:genders)` to get the gender id, that was making a lot of joins and slowing down the algorithm, I changed it to `Item.all.includes(:generalizations)` and the process is now running in 12 sec, which is not that great but its a progress!